# Nested If in laravel blade

Tags: laravel

My nested if not working properly. I wanted to first check a user is logged in or not, if logged in then I check the user id and the user id belongs to post is matched or not if matched then I want to show the link to edit or delete but, when I logged in I watched every post with edit/delete option. I marked with red color in picture

[image]

Comment: how about posting your code...

Comment: Also try using the middleware within the controller rather than on the view.

Comment: You should use `==` instead of `=` for comparison

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your controller:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

Then remove the `if (Auth::check())` statement from the view.

Also, this needs to be changed:

`if (Auth::user()->id == $variable )` not `if (Auth::user()->id = $variable)`